# Duplicate variable: sumofHiresLDCMapActual (attempt to re-create the variable with type: a)

Tags: apex

> Error: OrderPlacing Compile Error: Duplicate variable: sumofHiresLDCMapActual (attempt to re-create the variable with type: a) at line 2,014 column 21

Edit : Updating the error and adding the class
the error is thrown on addition of below code in a different method .

```
Basadj = [Select Baseline_Value__c from newobj__c where Year__c=:yearSelected and Month__c=:monthSelected and task__c='22' and Country__c =:country];
```

The class :

```
 public pagereference   recruitmentPrimaryDriverTwo() {
        List<CountrywiseVolume__c> cwvList = new List<CountrywiseVolume__c>();
        cwvList = [Select Id from CountrywiseVolume__c where Year__c=:yearSelected and Month__c=:monthSelected and  Driver__c=:driverIDMap.get('14').Record_Type_ID__c];
        if(cwvList.size()>0 && !test.isRunningTest()){

            ApexPages.addMessage(new ApexPages.Message(ApexPages.Severity.ERROR,'Records for this period have already been generated.'));
        }
        else{

            list<CountrywiseVolume__c> insertCVList = new list<CountrywiseVolume__c>();// HOLDS ALL THE COUNTRYWISE VOLUME RECORDS        
            Set<String> keySet = new Set<String>();
            //FETCH THE VOLUME INFO FOR PRIMARY DRIVER TWO FROM DRIVERUTIL CLASS 
            map<string, decimal> sumofHiresLDCMap = new map<string, decimal>();
            map<string, decimal> gradCountryMap = new map<string, decimal>(); 
            map<string, decimal> sumofHiresLDCBaselineAdjMap = new map<string, decimal>();

            map<string, decimal> **sumofHiresLDCMapActual** = new map<string, decimal>();
            map<string, Decimal> gradCountryMapActual = new map<string, Decimal>();
            map<string, decimal> sumofHiresLDCActualAdjMap = new map<string, decimal>();

            decimal baselineAdjst = 0.0;
            decimal actualAdjst = 0.0;
            //GR: Updated the code segment to implement CR 20. Baseline will be taken from DriverUtil for year 2013.                
            if(yearSelected == '2013' || yearSelected == '2012'){                   
                sumofHiresLDCMap = driverUtil.hiresInPrimaryLDClocations(monthSelected,yearSelected);//Baseline for 2013                    
                gradCountryMap = driverUtil.gradVolumeInfo(monthSelected,yearSelected);//Baseline grad data for 2013
                **sumofHiresLDCBaselineAdjMap** = VolumeAdjustment.getRecruitmentDriverFourteen(monthSelected,string.valueof(integer.valueof(yearSelected)-1));
            }
            else{

                sumofHiresLDCMap = RecruitmentDriverUtil.recruitmentVolumeActual(monthSelected,yearSelected,'14','baseline');//Baseline from Taleo
                gradCountryMap = RecruitmentDriverUtil.recruitmentGradDataActual(monthSelected,yearSelected,'14','baseline');//Baseline Grad data from taleo
                sumofHiresLDCBaselineAdjMap = RecruitmentDriverUtil.getRecruitmentDriverTaleo(monthSelected,string.valueof(integer.valueof(yearSelected)-1),'14');
            }
            // FETCH GRAD VOLUME INFO 
            if(yearSelected == '2012'){                  
                **sumofHiresLDCMapActual** = driverUtilActual.hiresInPrimaryLDClocationsActual(monthSelected,yearSelected);
                gradCountryMapActual = driverUtilActual.gradVolumeInfoActual(monthSelected,yearSelected);
                sumofHiresLDCActualAdjMap = VolumeAdjustment.getRecruitmentDriverFourteen(monthSelected,yearSelected);
            }
            else{
                **sumofHiresLDCMapActual** = RecruitmentDriverUtil.recruitmentVolumeActual(monthSelected,yearSelected,'14','actual');//Actual from Taleo
                gradCountryMapActual = RecruitmentDriverUtil.recruitmentGradDataActual(monthSelected,yearSelected,'14','actual');//Actual grad data from taleo
                sumofHiresLDCActualAdjMap = RecruitmentDriverUtil.getRecruitmentDriverTaleo(monthSelected,yearSelected,'14');
            }               
            if(yearSelected == '2012'){
                if(gradCountryMap!=null && gradCountryMap.keySet()!=null) {keySet.addAll(gradCountryMap.keySet());}
                if(gradCountryMapActual!=null && gradCountryMapActual.keySet()!=null) {keySet.addAll(gradCountryMapActual.keySet());}
            }
            else{
                if(sumofHiresLDCMapActual!=null && sumofHiresLDCMapActual.keySet()!=null) {keySet.addAll(sumofHiresLDCMapActual.keySet()); }
            }
            for(string recHire : keySet){

                // INDEX 0--> MONTH, INDEX 1--> COUNTRY
                CountrywiseVolume__c recCountryVolume = new CountrywiseVolume__c(Month__c = monthSelected,Country__c = recHire.split('-')[1],Year__c = yearSelected, driver__c = driverIDMap.get('14').Record_Type_ID__c,recordtypeid = rtCWVMap.get(UnileverTextConstant.SERVICELINE_RECRUITMENT));

                if(sumofHiresLDCMap.containsKey(recHire)){
                    baselineAdjst = (sumofHiresLDCMap.get(recHire)!=null?sumofHiresLDCMap.get(recHire):0);
                }
                if(sumofHiresLDCBaselineAdjMap !=null && sumofHiresLDCBaselineAdjMap.containsKey(recHire)){
                    baselineAdjst += sumofHiresLDCBaselineAdjMap.get(recHire);
                    recCountryVolume.BaselineAdjustment__c = sumofHiresLDCBaselineAdjMap.get(recHire);
                }
                else if(! sumofHiresLDCBaselineAdjMap.containsKey(recHire) && !sumofHiresLDCMap.containsKey(recHire) ){  
                    baselineAdjst = 0;}
                if(sumofHiresLDCMapActual.containsKey(recHire)){
                    actualAdjst = (sumofHiresLDCMapActual.get(recHire)!=null?sumofHiresLDCMapActual.get(recHire):0.0);
                }
                if(sumofHiresLDCActualAdjMap !=null && sumofHiresLDCActualAdjMap.containsKey(recHire)){
                    actualAdjst += sumofHiresLDCActualAdjMap.get(recHire);
                    recCountryVolume.ActualAdjustment__c = sumofHiresLDCActualAdjMap.get(recHire);
                }
                else if(! sumofHiresLDCActualAdjMap.containsKey(recHire) && !sumofHiresLDCMapActual.containsKey(recHire)){
                    actualAdjst = 0; }
                if(gradCountryMap.containsKey(recHire)){
                    recCountryVolume.BaselineGradVolume__c = (gradCountryMap.get(recHire)!=null?gradCountryMap.get(recHire):0.0);
                }else{recCountryVolume.BaselineGradVolume__c = 0.0;}
                if(gradCountryMapActual.containsKey(recHire)){
                    recCountryVolume.ActualGradVolume__c = (gradCountryMapActual.get(recHire)!=null?gradCountryMapActual.get(recHire):0.0);
                }else{recCountryVolume.ActualGradVolume__c  =0.0;}

                recCountryVolume.BaselineVolume__c = baselineAdjst;
                recCountryVolume.ActualVolume__c = actualAdjst;
                recCountryVolume.ULActualVolume__c = recCountryVolume.ActualGradVolume__c + recCountryVolume.ActualVolume__c;
                recCountryVolume.ULBaselineVolume__c = recCountryVolume.BaselineGradVolume__c + recCountryVolume.BaselineVolume__c ;        
                baselineAdjst = 0.0;  // RE-SET FOR FURTHER USE
                actualAdjst = 0.0;
                insertCVList.add(recCountryVolume);    
            }
            try{
                if(insertCVList.size()>0)   insert insertCVList;               
            }catch(exception insertEx){
                system.debug('Insert failed '+insertEx.getMessage());
            }   
        }
        return null;
    }
```

Comment: Can you show us your Apex class? Normally this error is pretty self-explanitory. At some point you've declared a variable called ordermethod and tried to redeclare it somewhere else, hence why it can't compile.

Comment: @Poet I am adding a new query to the method which no way uses the old variable ordermethod. Can it be due to reusage of Year__c=:yearSelected and Month__c=:monthSelected variables?

Comment: You should be able to redeclare variables with the same names in separate methods.  You haven't named two methods "ordermethod" have you? Might help editting your question and posting your class.

Comment: @Poet Updated the class with variable name sumofHiresLDCMapActual.